# jqgrid not showing the rows of data

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

When i try load up the jqgrid it shows the header, but doesn't add any of the rows with the data in it.
Link of the picture here -->
[Image of problem I am having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shp2R.jpg)

**Controller**

```
package mobilesuits

import grails.converters.JSON
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class MobileSuitsController {

def scaffold = MobileSuits
/**
 * This function renders the json for the listGrid displayed on the home page
 * "listAllComicBook" corresponds to the url supplied in jqgrid
 * The first 5 lines are boiler plate found on all(i think) DCmd jqgrids
 * The create criteria creates a corresponding sql table of the comic book attributes
 *      The if statements inside the create criteria allow for searching in at the top of each column
 * The ' '  in the collection corresponds to the editing action for a row on the grid -- the little pin widget
 *
 */

def listAllMobileSuits = {
    def sortIndex = params.sidx ?: 'name'
    def sortOrder = params.sord ?: 'asc'
    def maxRows = Integer.valueOf(params.rows)
    def currentPage = Integer.valueOf(params.page) ?:1
    def rowOffset = currentPage == 1 ? 0 : (currentPage -1) * maxRows
    def mobilesuits = MobileSuits.createCriteria().list(max: maxRows, offset: rowOffset){
        if (params.name) ilike('name', "%${params.name}%")
        if (params.model) ilike('model', "%${params.model}%")
        if (params.affiliation) ilike('affiliation', "%${params.affiliation}%")
        if (params.pilot) ilike('pilot', "%${params.pilot}%")
    }
    def totalRows = mobilesuits.totalCount
    def numberOfPages = Math.ceil(totalRows / maxRows)
    //the first attribute in the collection is for the edit feature action thing
    def results = mobilesuits?.collect{[cell: ['', it.name, it.model, it.affiliation, it.pilot], id: it.id]}
    def jsonData = [rows: results, page: currentPage, records: totalRows, total: numberOfPages]
    render jsonData as JSON
}

/**
 * This function allows for the editing of a row in the jqgrid
 * "editAllComicBook" corresponds to the edit URL in the jqgrid
 * Whether the attribute is editable or not depends on how you initialize the editable field for the attribute in ColModel in jqgrid
 */
def editAllMobileSuits = {
    def item = null
    def message = ""
    def state = "FAIL"
    def id


    params.theObject = MobileSuits.get(params.id)

    if(params.name)
        params.theObject.name = params.name
    if(params.model)
        params.theObject.model = params.model
    if(params.affiliation)
        params.theObject.affiliaiton = params.affiliation
    if(params.pilot)
        params.theObject.pilot = params.pilot


    if (! params.theObject.hasErrors() && params.theObject.save()) {
        id = params.theObject.id
        state = "OK"
    }
    def response = [state:state,id:id]
    render response as JSON

  }
}
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {//code goes here
    jQuery("#allMobileSuits").jqGrid({
        heigth: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        caption: 'Mobile Suits List',
        url: 'MobileSuits/mobileSuits',
        editurl: 'MobileSuits/editAllMobileSuits',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['Name', 'Model', 'Affiliation', 'Pilot'],
        colModel: [
            //the actions column corresponds to the editurl
          /* {name:'actions', index:'actions', editable:false,    required:false, sortable:false, search:false, width:40, fixed: true, frozen: true,
                formatter: 'actions', hidden:false, formatoptions: {
                afterSave: function(e) {
                    $("#allMobileSuits").trigger("reloadGrid");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                                $('#allMobileSuits').jqGrid('resetSelection');
                                $('#allMobileSuits').jqGrid('setSelection', e);
                            }, 200
                    );
                }
            }},*/
            {name:'name', width:200, editable:true},
            {name:'model', width:200, editable:true},
            {name:'affiliation', width:200, editable:true},
            {name:'pilot', width:200, editable:true}

        ],

        rowNum:20,
        rowList:[20,40,60],
        gridview: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        autowidth:true,
       // scroll: true,
        forceFit:true,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        pager: '#mobileSuitsAllPager',
        scrollOffset:0,
        gridComplete: function() {
        }
    });
    jQuery("#allMobileSuits").jqGrid('navGrid','#mobileSuitsAllPager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});


    %{-- function to allow for searching a column for some string--}%
    jQuery('#allMobileSuits').filterToolbar({id:'allMobileSuits', searchOnEnter:true});
    $("#allMobileSuits").jqGrid('navGrid','#mobileSuitsAllPager',{
                add:false,
                del:false,
                edit:false,
                refresh:false,
                refreshstate:"current",
                search:false
            },
            {},//edit options

            {recreateForm:true //since clearAfterAdd is trueby default, recreate the form so we re-establish value for parent id
            });

    %{--Not sure what exactly this does--}%
    jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({

        pager : '#allMobileSuitsPager',

    });
    %{--Not sure what exactly this does--}%
    jQuery("#grid_id").navGrid('#allMobileSuitsPager',"add_allMobileSuits" );



    jQuery(window).bind('resize', function() {

    }).trigger('resize');
});



</script>


%{--tag for grid--}%
<table id="allMobileSuits"></table>
%{--tag for pager--}%
<div id="mobileSuitsAllPager"></div>
```

I am not sure if I have a problem in my controller or view to determine why I can not see the data I add to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was wrong with why the data was not showing. It was both my url and editUrl lines. I thought that was the url I wanted the data to go to, but instead replaced it with listAllMobileSuits for url and editAllMobileSuits for editURl which were the function name of the list and edit for the grid I have in my controller.

So turned

```
url: 'MobileSuits/mobileSuits',
editurl: 'MobileSuits/editAllMobileSuits',
```

into

```
url: 'listAllMobileSuits',
editurl: 'editAllMobileSuits',
```